# "Sehen Sie, es geht doch."

Tags: translation

Sorry, but this is one of those situations where the dictionary is useless.

The source is at around 00:20:26 of

http://www.ardmediathek.de/tv/Tatort/Tatort-Das-Dorf/hr-fernsehen/Video?bcastId=34483450&documentId=48208382

Murot at that point says:

> Sehen Sie, es geht doch.

What does that mean?

Of course, I understand the "Sehen Sie" bit.  It's the "es geht doch" part that I can't sort out.  Literally it would mean something like "it goes [on], however", or "it works, however", but none of this makes sense in context.

<strike>One tentative translation (PLEASE, correct me if I'm wrong):</strike>

> <strike>You see, there's more [to it], though.</strike>

Comment: As you see, it is possible to do that. Sehen Sie, es ist doch möglich.

Comment: https://www.deepl.com/translator  "Look, you can do it."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The translation would be something like "`Look, it can be done`". Allthough, even after watching from ca. 18:00 it's not completely clear to me what the guy refers to ...

Answer (score 6):

*Gehen* is one of the most often used verbs in German language. Just *haben, sein, werden* and *können* are more often used. *Stehen, sagen, sollen, wollen, kommen, geben, machen* and *müssen* are used with the same 
frequency as *gehen*. All other German verbs are used less often.

But I think, it is the most flexible verb in German language. [Wiktionary](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/gehen) lists 24 different meanings of the verb *gehen*, You should get familiar with them.

The meaning, you found, is listed as #11 in the list in Wiktionary:

[11] funktionieren, machbar sein

In English: to function/work/operate/perform, to be makeable/possible/feasible

Here are some examples:

> Heute *gehe* ich zu Fuß, denn mein Auto **geht** nicht.
>   Today I *walk*, because my car doesn't **work**.
>
> Kannst du morgen kommen? - Ja, das **geht**.
>   Can you come tomorrow? - Yes, this **is possible**.